# How to suppress based-class property in favor of the same new derived-class property on model creating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a base class `MyBaseClass`, with a wrapper class `MyWrapperClass` which is derived from that base class. The purpose of declaring wrapper class is to detaching the EntityFramework-related annotations, `Id` properties and navigation properties from the base class. The structure of base class and derived class are as follows:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
   public ClassA MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyWrapperClass: MyBaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public new ClassAWrapper MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot use `virtual...override` pattern on `MyProperty`, because of the differet types for `MyProperty` in base class and derived class.
Thus, i put `new` keyword before `MyProperty` property, and i expect the EntityFramework to create the model based on `ClassAWrapper` instead of `ClassA`.
But i get an error when trying to `add-migration`: **"`ClassA` should have a key"**.  While `ClassA` has not a key property, but `ClassAWrapper` has.
`DbContext` implementation is as follows:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyDerivedClass> MyDerivedClass { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Problem:** I need to tell the EntityFramework to give up on the `MyProperty` class of the base class (which is of type `ClassA`), and look at the same property in the derive class (with type `ClassAWrapper`) when creating the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NotMapped` and `Key` data annotations, like this:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
   [NotMapped]
   public ClassA MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyWrapperClass: MyBaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public new ClassAWrapper MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```